# Python. Помогите, работа со строками

Tags: python

Например:
text = "какой то текст"
Нужно вывести text без "какой", как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если вам нужно убрать конкретное количество букв в начале, вы можете вывести так:

```py
text = "какой то текст"
print(text[len('какой '):]) # то же самое, что print(text[6:])
```

2. Если нужно убрать именно первое слово, независимо от его длины, это можно сделать так:

```py
text = "какой то текст"
print(text.split(' ', 1)[1])
```

Но только при условии, что в строке есть хотя бы один пробел

Результат:

```
то текст
```

Comment: А еще можно реплейсить и использовать регэкспы)